# cardview with recyclerview whose max height should be in some dp and minheight to wrap content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a `CardView` with a `RecyclerView`.

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:cardElevation="4dp">

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/white" />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The mentioned height "300dp" should be the maximum height of this card. If there are less items for `RecyclerView` then it should be `wrap_content`.

Basically, the height should be wrap content with max height of 300dp.

Kindly guide me how to achieve it

It is inside `NestedScrollView`.
I've tried with height 0dp for `CardView`.
I've 3 other such cards with hold `RecyclerViews`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = yourRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        yourRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = yourRecyclerView.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = yourRecyclerView.getMeasuredWidth();
        Log.d(TAG, "height: " + finalHeight + " width: " + finalWidth);
        if (finalHeight < 300) {
            yourCardView.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(
                    CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, finalHeight));
            yourCardView.setMinimumHeight(10);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:minHeight="300dp"`
and `android:maxHeight="wrap_content"` then your layout height should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so your code should look like this

```
           <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:maxheight="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

this should work

Comment: Unknown attribute `android:maxheight`

Comment: Write this way
            android:minHeight=""

Comment: @Prabs, the min or max height should be like this: android:minHeight="value" and android:maxHeight="value" respectively

Answer (score 0):

You are set your card layout `android:layout_height` as `wrap_content` and add one more attribute for the maximum height of the CardView  `android:maxHeight="300dp"`

```
           <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Unknown attribute `android:maxheight`

Comment: @Prabs Sorry it is not android:maxheight it is android:maxHeight. It is capital H in maxHeight